# how to overload division and be compatible with __future__ division in Python 2.x

Tags: python, operator-overloading, division

How can I use both `from __future__ import division` and overload division in the same Python 2.x script?

In Python, I can usually override the division operator by introducing a `__div__` and/or `__rdiv__` method, e.g.

```
class A:
    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return 2.1

a = A()

print 3/a
```

If I run the above in a fresh Python 2.7.6 interpreter, it displays `2.1`, the expected result.

If, on the other hand, I begin with a `from __future__ import division`, then the code fails with a:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'instance'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the `__div__`/`__rdiv__` method, give `A` a [`__truediv__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__) and/or `__rtruediv__` method to be called when `from __future__ import division` is in effect.

(Also note that in Python 2 you really should make all your classes inherit from `object`.)